# Chart label overlapping in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

i am facing problem of label overlapping in primeFaces.

**i have customers records more than 50k** so i have to show it in chart all things are working perfect but problem is that, Active customers records are too many and inactive also pending customers are less than 50 so it is overlapping the label of Pending profile.

**Here is Bean:**

```
public void getALLCustomersProfileStatus() {

    MainDashboardModel db = new MainDashboardModel();
    db.getALLCustomersProfileStatus();
    pieModel = new PieChartModel();

    dashboardObj = db.getALLCustomersProfileStatus();
    int totalActive = 0;
    int totalInactive = 0;
    int totalPending = 0;

    if (dashboardObj != null) {
        totalActive = dashboardObj.getTotalActiveCustomerProfileCount();
        totalInactive = dashboardObj.getTotalInactiveCustomerProfileCount();
        totalPending = dashboardObj.getTotalPendingCustomerProfileCount();
        totalCustomerProfiles = (totalActive + totalInactive + totalPending);

    }


    pieModel.setFill(true);
    pieModel.setShowDataLabels(true);
    pieModel.setDiameter(150);
    pieModel.setShadow(false);
    pieModel.set("Active Profile", totalActive);
    pieModel.set("Inactive Profile", totalInactive);
    pieModel.set("Pending",( totalPending ));

    pieModel.setSeriesColors("2CC5A2,F05129,F28E8E");//#e69900

    pieModel.setLegendPosition("w");

}
```

**Here is xhtml:**

```
 <ui:define name="content">


    <div class="ui-g dashboard">

        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
            <div class="card overview">
                <div class="overview-content clearfix">
                    <span class="overview-title">Total Customer Profiles</span>
                    <span class="overview-detail">#{mainDashboardBean.totalCustomerProfiles}</span>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
            <p:panelGrid layout="grid" columns="2">
                <p:chart type="pie"  model="#{mainDashboardBean.pieModel}" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></p:chart>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </div>


</ui:define>
```

**Again i am explaining that data is fetching perfect but only overlapping issue facing.**
Pending profiles are only 26.

**Here is Image**
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Try if it works with plain jqplot